# Create full table structure dynamicaly with single loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create tabel which could have multiple rows.
I creating table on run time with javascript .
As of now did that with two loop

```
exlTb = document.getElementById('exlTb');
tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');

for(var i=0; i <= row; i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j = 0; j <= colomn; j++){
      var td = document.createElement('td'); 
      tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);  
   }
 tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
 exlTb.appendChild(tbl);
```

I am trying to optimize my solution

Comment: *"...with single loop...I am trying to optimize my solution..."* In what way is using two loops less than optimal? Optimize how? Faster? Clearer?

Comment: Try a templating system rather than building your table with DOM methods—in all likelihood they're the culprit here, not the nested loops.

Comment: yeah i thought if that could be done with single loop than it will be faster .

Comment: Funny assumption... Is building one car faster than building two bicycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to create the table more quickly, all those trips to and from the DOM layer are something you can get rid of. Browsers are *really really fast* at parsing HTML. When building tables dynamically like this, you're usually better off creating *markup* and then having the browser parse and create it all at once, because you're not crossing that JavaScript/DOM boundary all the time.

Here's one way:

```
exlTb = document.getElementById('exlTb');
var markup = ['<table><tbody>'];

for(var i=0; i <= row; i++){
    markup.push('<tr>');
    for(var j = 0; j <= colomn; j++){
      markup.push('<td></td>');
      }
    markup.push('</tr>');
   }
markup.push('</tbody></table>');
exlTb.innerHTML = markup.join(""); // <== Note: Assumes exlTb is otherwise empty
```

Building the markup up in an array and then combining it *once* at the end is quicker in many (but not all) cases than string concatenation. I expect if you look around, there's a http://jsperf.com test already out there comparing...

Comment: does this push and join function are faster and better than append ??

Comment: @mayank: You mean faster than `createElement` / `appendChild`? Usually, yeah. As I said above: *"When building tables dynamically like this, you're usually better off creating markup and then having the browser parse and create it all at once, because you're not crossing that JavaScript/DOM boundary all the time."* Naturally, you'd want to test it with your target browsers and with your real table data.

Comment: Crowder : I have tested same on http://jsperf.com/domtable but result seems to be different. loop with append function working faster .check this link  http://jsperf.com/domtable

Comment: @mayank: Things are changing for the better. :-) Back in the day the markup approach was a **lot** faster. Now it can depend on the size and such of the table, compare with http://jsperf.com/domtable/2 Firefox is happier with the markup solution (Chrome still prefers the DOM). I, for one, will be thrilled if we can (soon?) ditch markup-based updates...